# ArrayList. Joining String values in one index

Tags: java, arraylist

I think someone was asking this question already but still.

I have ArrayList of random String values and I need to put those values into another ArrayList but only in one index.

Example:

I have

```
{ "hey","how","are","you"}
```

and I need to make it

```
{"Hey how are you"}
```

Is there is some kind of command like join or smth? because I tried adding another String value to the same index but it only replaced it.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: For StackOverflow questions please be more specific. Show the exact code you tried and explain what's happening. The fact that this question has five answers in less than ten minutes doesn't bode well for the quality of this question. Edit: And now it's eight. Go people go! Get that sweet karma!

Comment: I have tried StringJoiner way and it worked of course. Thanks for that guys. I just started programming and that why I could`nt find the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a StringJoiner for that solution.

```
List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<>();  //The one to contain all Strings from yourList
List<String> yourList = Arrays.asList("Hey", "how", "are", "you");    //The list of Strings

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" "); //Space as delimiter, strings will be separated with spaces
for (String s : yourlist) {
    joiner.add(s);
}
mainList.add(joiner.toString());    //Add the new concatenated String to your list, in a single string
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 added a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class which does exactly what you want (the following code is in Java 9):

```
    List<String> list = List.of("hey", "how", "are", "you");
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    list.forEach(str -> joiner.add(str));
    System.out.println(joiner.toString()); // hey how are you
    // and if you want the final result to be in a list
    // Java 9:
    list = List.of(joiner.toString());
    // anything before Java 9
    list = Arrays.asList(joiner.toString());
```

Another (simpler) way to do it (since Java 8):

```
String.join(" ", list)
```

Comment: downvoter - care to comment ?

Comment: OP didn't show any efforts and I believe we should vote for closing the question other than answer it.

Comment: @haifzhan Thanks for your response. This is not a good reason to downvote an answer. If you hover the mouse over the down-arrow you'll see that it'll show you a tooltip saying: "this answer isn't useful". So even if one thinks that the *question* is problematic - that should *not* be the reason to downvote an answer. The only valid reason to downvote an answer is if it's not useful!

Comment: I have removed the downvote but insist my point.

Comment: I agree with @haifzhan. The answer isn't useful because the question isn't useful. You can't have a useful answer to a useless question. It all just adds to the noise.

Comment: @DavidS I disagree with both of you, anyone that wants to join strings, googles it and finds this question now sees at least 3 different ways in which it can be done. I consider the question useful even if the OP didn't show effort (which I agree - is not a good behavior).

Comment: @haifzhan that ^ respond is for you as well (I can tag only one per comment)

Comment: Any one who Googles it would have already found a million answers. How many times must the exact same question be asked before it's no longer useful?

Comment: @DavidS if the same question was asked before we can consider it as a dup and close it as such. It will still be helpful to link the two!

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` to join multiple strings

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
listA.forEach(item -> sb.append(item));

listB.add(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

commons.lang3.StringUtils

StringUtils.join(Object array[],String separator)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be something like:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "))));
```